# Помогите с анимацией пожалуйста

Tags: css, анимация, transform

почему меню появляется моментально, а не плавно?

```
<header>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="header__content">
              <div class="header__logo">
                  <img src="../dist/img/svg/logo.svg" alt="#">
              </div>
              <div class="header__nav" id="mobileMenu">
                   <nav>
                       <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Как это работает?</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Для кого</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Кейсы</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Тарифы</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Безопасность</a></li>
                           <li class="header___link_mobile"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                           <li class="header___link_mobile"><button class="header___link_button">Вход</button></li>
                       </ul>
                   </nav>
                   <div class="header__lang">
                       <a href="#">RU</a>
                       <a href="#">EN</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="header__button">
                       <button>Подключиться</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="header__burger burger" id="burgerButton">
                  <div class="burger__line"></div>
                  <div class="burger__line"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="header__nav_mobile">
              <nav>
                       <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Как это работает?</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Для кого</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Кейсы</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Тарифы</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Безопасность</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </nav>
          </div> -->
      </div>
   </header>
.header__nav{
   display: flex;
   nav{
       display: none;
       transform: translateY(-1000px);
       transition: all 1s linear;
   }
}
.header__nav_active{
   overflow-y: hidden;
   nav{
       transform: translateY(38px);
       transition: all 1s linear;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       height: 90vh;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #000;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       ul{
           padding: 0;
           list-style-type: none;
           li{
               text-align: center;
               margin-bottom: 20px;
               a{
                   text-decoration: none;
                   font-size: 18px;
                   line-height: 23px;
                   letter-spacing: 0.96px;
                   color: #555E68;
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: можно пожалустО HTML код

Comment: @AndreyFreiz добавил

Comment: display - не анимируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказал **[@Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165192/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0#comment2022491_1165192)** в комментариях:

> display - не анимируется

Но есть вариант, допустим вам нужно плавное появление и исчезновение, то можно сделать следующее:

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('--active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*  */
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.overlay.--active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle">Открыть</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="toggle">Закрыть</div>
</div>
```

---

Вариант с увеличением.

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('--active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*  */
  transform: scale(0);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.overlay.--active {
  transform: scale(1);
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle">Открыть</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="toggle">Закрыть</div>
</div>
```

Но варианты хромают, кто как..

Первый вариант может быть прозрачным, но иметь таргет зоны, если `pointer-events` не поддерживается браузером. О поддержке - [ссылка](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Второй вариант тоже в принципе может отображаться постоянно, если браузер не поддерживает [`transform: scale`](https://caniuse.com/#search=scale)

Comment: @UModeL, чёт я задумался :D Спасибо, исправил